# Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://my-previous-db

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, h2

I try to use H2 database in my new project, before I used postgres. Wrote all data in application.properties, also there is nothing about postgres driver in pom file, only H2 driver, but during auto-configuration each time it tries to connect to my previous database as a result shows this error.

`Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:postgresql://{my-previous-db-url}`

Could anyone help to solve the problem?

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
spring.datasource.name=taco
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:taco
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MyProject</name>
    <description>TacoExample</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have no idea what to do, tried to find any info about parent pom.file but had no success

**UPDATE:** also forgtot that if I specify datasource bean in configuration, everything is ok. But I can't understand where does Spring boot takes the URL to the previos database by Autoconfiguration

Comment: try to clean-compile your project, and invalidate caches/restart your idea.

Comment: Check your IDE and environment for a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` variable which will always override the one configured in the `application.properties`.

Comment: There was such a env var in environmental vars as SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL but have already deleted and no effect and clean-compile also doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

This error is attributed to the project have not compile.You use spring-boot-devtools in the project.But the plug-in stops compiling automatically duing running or debugging, at this time need build the project.

You can do this:

1. Stop the project,delete the target folder and build the project.
2. Run project and have a try.

You also need check idea conifg adout devtools,something might be wrong.
And you can use Jrebel instead of devtools.